# Why is my Mongoose find query not returning the expected data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The following function is to return all menu items of a specific type. The types exist in the database but the query is returning no data. Without the query criterion: {type:menuItem}, it returns the data with the the type.

```
exports.get = async (menuItem) => {
    console.log(chalk.green('menuItem', menuItem));  

    try {      
        const menu = await Menu.find({type:menuItem});
        console.log('menu', menu);
        return menu;      
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }    
}
```

MenuItem logged to the console as shown in the function above produces the following. The problem seem to be with the variable, menuItem, because when I hard-code, {type:'pizza'}, it works.

```
console.log(chalk.green('menuItem', menuItem));  
menuItem 'pizza'
```

The anuglar query string looks like the following, is there a problem with this:

```
private menuUrl = '/api/menu?menuItem="pizza"';
```

Sample data from the database:

```
{ quantity: 1,
    toppings: [ 'chipotle-steak', 'red-onions' ],
    _id: 5d163a7ae7179a4e432b501a,
    type: 'pizza',
    name: 'CHIPOTLE STEAK',
    price: 15,
    img: 'Chipotle-Steak.png',
}
```

Comment: does it work for `name`? is `type` reserved somehow?

Comment: I think you're on to something. It does work for name. I am going to change the filed name, type, in the database and see how it goes.

Comment: You may be able to do `Menu.find({"type":menuItem})`

Comment: @ktilcu I changed the field name but the result is still the same.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the variable, menuItem, because when I hard-code, {item:'pizza'}, it works.

Comment: does string matches exactly as what is stored in the database collection?

Answer (score 0):

The key `type` is used to tell `mongoose` about the `type` of that particular field. thats why using `type` as a field in mongoose schema can sometimes behave ambiguously.

Kindly change `type` to `kind` and search with `{kind : menuItem}` and it should work for you.

**Dont forget to update all the docs from `type` to `kind`.**

**To update :**

```
Menu.update({},{$rename : {'type' : 'kind'}},{multi:true})
```

Then find using `kind`

```
const menu = await Menu.find({kind:menuItem});
```

Comment: I previously changed type to 'item' but the problem persists.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the variable, menuItem, because when I hard-code, {item:'pizza'}, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake. The Angular query string had single quotes around pizza:

```
 private menuUrl = "/api/menu?menuItem='pizza'";
```

It should have been without quotes instead:

```
 private menuUrl = "/api/menu?menuItem=pizza";
```